# How to log in to chat application with spring security username

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, stomp

I'm new in Spring and I trying log in to chat application with spring security username.
But controller or stomp don't recognize input. And don't allows to enter chat
Where is I should to write in stomp or controller?
Thank you.

Chat  Controller

```java
@Controller
public class ChatController {
    
        @GetMapping("/chat")
        public String chat() {
        return "chat";
    }
    @MessageMapping("/chat.sendMessage")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessagePojo sendMessage(@Payload ChatMessagePojo chatMessagePojo) {
        return chatMessagePojo;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/chat.addUser")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessagePojo addUser(@Payload ChatMessagePojo chatMessagePojo, SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
        
// Add username in web socket session
    headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("email", chatMessagePojo.getSender());
        return chatMessagePojo;
    }
```

ChatMessage class

```java
public class ChatMessagePojo {
 private MessageType type;
 private String content;
 private String sender;

        public enum MessageType {
            CHAT,
            JOIN,
            LEAVE
        }
    
    }
```

Stomp

```js
const connect = () => {
    const Stomp = require("stompjs");
    var SockJS = require("sockjs-client");
    SockJS = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/ws");
    stompClient = Stomp.over(SockJS);
    stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);
  };
const onConnected = () => {
    console.log("connected");

    stompClient.subscribe(
      "/user/" + currentUser.id + "/queue/messages",
      onMessageReceived
    );
  };
const sendMessage = (msg) => {
    if (msg.trim() !== "") {
      const message = {
        senderId: currentUser.id,
        recipientId: activeContact.id,
        senderName: currentUser.name,
        recipientName: activeContact.name,
        content: msg,
        timestamp: new Date(),
      };
        
      stompClient.send("/app/chat", {}, JSON.stringify(message));
    }
  };
```

Example login screen to chat:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried but failed, and then I solved it with my own solution. Maybe you can refer to it.

1. Make a socket endpoint for authentication and send the ID and password for authentication.
2. Save id and session after successful authentication.
3. Then get the user id through the session map `SESSION_USERID`.

Frontend

```js
stompClient.send("/app/chat/login", {}, "{type: AUTH, data: {id: 'mock', pwd: '12345678'}}");
```

Backend

```java
public static final Map<String, Long> SESSION_USERID = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

@Override
public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
    // parse message to object
    if (message.type == AUTH) {
        // do auth
        // if auth succeed, cache the user
        SESSION_USERID.put(userId, session.getId());
    } else if (message.type == CHAT) {
        Long userId = SESSION_USERID.get(session.getId());
        if (userId == null) {
            // Send error or close session
        } else {
            // Send messages to other peoples
        }
    }

}

//----
```